# How to prove $ \mathrm{e}^x\left|\int_x^{x+1}\sin\mathrm e^t \,\mathrm d t\right|\leqslant 2$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to prove $$
\mathrm{e}^x\left|\int_x^{x+1}\sin\mathrm e^t \,\mathrm d t\right|\leqslant 2.
$$
I tried to use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality and some other basic integral inequalities but failed.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: The sharper bound $1.4$ also seems to hold but I don't know how to prove it

Comment: @metamorphy [Follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3573887/631742)